# Crontab to run a java shell script on linux

Tags: java, linux, cron

Am writing a simple java script to send email it works perfectly however it does work in the
crontab.
the command sh sendmail.sh works

Here is my crontab command from crontab -e

```
*/5 * * * * sh  user /home/user/classes/sendmail.sh
```

I expect this to work and send mail every 5 minutes but it doesn't work

However the command `sh sendmail.sh works`

I need help on the crontab

Comment: Your cron expression is correct, can you give us additional details?

Comment: can you add the content of sendmail.sh

Comment: java -classpath .:mail.jar:imap.jar:dsn.jar:smtp.jar:gimap.jar:mailapi.jar:pop3.jar email.Email     nothing happens from the crontab job and no email is sent

Comment: Note- By default crontab sends a mail to user account executing the cronjob, why dont you make use of it?

Comment: i got this message from  cat /var/spool/mail/user               /bin/sh: user: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys but I found the solution

this code works

```
*/5 * * * * (cd /home/user/classes; sh mail.sh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your correct lines is the following

`*/5 * * * * user /home/user/classes/sendmail.sh` (without "sh" word)

You have to be aware that user "user" has permission to execute the script "sendmail.sh"

You can see that executing `ls -la sendmail.sh` and reading who is the owner and the permissions.

Comment: */5 * * * * (cd /home/user/classes; sh mail.sh) thanks this worked